# How to limit the size of suggestion drop down in sap.m.multicombobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, sapui5

I am using **sap.m.multicombobox** within a page and that page has footer. I am placing this multicombobox in the page header.Now if I click the multicombobox dropdown button then it will show all the suggestions and this is blocking the footer buttons. So I want to limit the size of dropdown suggestions without setting the suggestion limit. if there are more suggestions dropdown should come but it should be there within footer content.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property directly available to set the size of the dropdown. There is a way to do it, but let me warn you that it is not the standard approach to do it. When you try to select a value inside a Combobox/MultiCombobox, it will create a Popover control inside which is a List control. You can set the height to this Popover by getting the reference to the internal Popover control.

```
var oCombo = this.byId("MyComboBox"),
        oPopOver = oCombo.getPicker();
oPopOver.setContentHeight("400px"); //Set height accordingly
```